# What is the max size limit for using split and cat combination?

Tags: ubuntu, files, filesystems, cat, split

I have backed up a file in zip format on Ubuntu whose size is 6.5GB. Trying to transfer it to a USB stick so needed to split since I got error “file size too large” while copying. (Ideally I want my USB to move between mac/ubuntu/windows.)

Managed to use `split` command and created chunks of 1GB each which copied successfully to the stick.

Now trying to combine the files using `cat x* >> backup.zip` gives me again error “file size too large”.

Can you help me understand what are the file size limits applicable. I am not sure if cat is complaining about the chunk sizes or the final output size.

Comment: On what operating and file system are you trying to combine the files back?

Comment: Maximum file size is a property of the filesystem. The USB drive is probably formatted as FAT32, which has a 4 GB limit. What you have on the location you're trying to combine the files in is anyone's guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `cat` command has practically no limit, and is only bounded by your system capabilities in terms of disk space and RAM.

The error "file size too large" you are seeing comes from the limitations of the filesystem on which you are trying to write the file. Most USB sticks are preformatted as FAT32, which cannot store files larger than 4 Gb (minus one byte). You should format the USB stick as NTFS, which has a max file size of 256 Tb. (There is a plethora of filesystem types, but NTFS is the one which is natively recognized by Windows and MacOS, so it will allow you to read your USB stick on any computer.)

Comment: Or Ext4 if Windows/Mac compatibility isn't an issue

Comment: Or exfat if you want to use it everywhere.

Comment: thanks... moment before I write this comment, I came to same conclusion.

Comment: Ideally I want my USB to move between mac/ubuntu/windows..

Comment: NTFS is the way to go then.